# I need to repeat this hash function x amount of times but I'm a bit lost now

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I am trying to make a script that starts with a secret, then hashes it, and hashes that, written in Javascript w/Node. I need to repeat that process 5 million times. The basis for the code is simple but the execution is what's slowing me down. This is what I have so far.

```
const secret = "Secret";  // Make the secret a const so it won't change.
var sha256 = require('sha256'); // Set-up sha256
var prehash = sha256(secret);  // Set variable 'prehash' to the hash of 'secret'
console.log(prehash);  // Display the hash
currentHash = sha256(prehash);  //Hash the previous hash
console.log(currentHash); //display the new hash
```

I need for it to do a couple things:

1. Hash a secret. (Done)
2. Hash the hash. (Done)
3. Repeat that 5 million times.

This is where the problem comes in.

Attempted Solution #1
If I start reassigning variables I lose track of which hash is being hashed since I have to set each iteration to a new var. This is time consuming and I can't check millions of line of code for 1 misspelled variable only to find that it wasn't properly invoked.

Attempted Solution #2
After the secret, I could try to assign the new hashes to preHash and currentHash respectively but I think it sets the value to the string representation of the variable not the value itself. Here's what I mean.

```
var preHash = sha256(secret);
currentHash = sha256(preHash);
preHash = currentHash;
currentHash = sha256(preHash);
```

If they happen in this order, I can expect

1. preHash to = the hash of 'secret'
2. currentHash = the hash of preHash
3. preHash is set to be = currentHash which at the time means sha256(preHash)
4. currentHash is set to be = sha256 of the new preHash

Does this mean that @ step 3, preHash = currentHash or

preHash = sha256(preHash)?

I've also been looking into the docs for node and js to see if i can;

1. Write each output of `console.log` to a file or
2. Export as a CSV file.

But I haven't been able to find anything that makes sense.

Comment: Why not use a recursive function with bails after a count of 5 million? That'd be my naive approach

Comment: I'm coming from Python trying my hand at Javascript. How would you make this function recursive. Would I ``` function recurse() { currentHash = sha256(preHash);
preHash = currentHash;
currentHash = sha256(preHash); recurse();```  ?

Comment: Just for clarity, is the request to hash one secret 5 million times or to hash 5 million secrets twice? I'm assuming it's the latter.

Comment: Are you asking how to hash something 5 millions times? `hash(hash(hash(hash(...))))`

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to hash a secret, then hash that hash, and hash that etc...

Comment: Including the secret everytime? Or is that only the first time?

Comment: The problem with hash(hash(hash(...)) Is that I'd have to write that about 5 millions times, I'd like to shorten the code if possible.

Comment: The secret  gets hashed first then I hash the hash of the secret and continue from there.

Comment: So it's not a salted hash, just a chain of hashes starting from a hash of a secret and hashing every hash I get until 5 million hashes are made.

Comment: Why not use a loop? `var hash = secret; for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; ++i) hash = sha256(hash);`

Comment: Would this loop be a recursive loop function or just a loop. Is there a difference in Javascript?

Comment: @Ozyman yes there is a difference.

Comment: A bit late now, but many hash algorithms explicitly call out that repeatedly rehashing the result of the previous hash, does no good at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an iterative solution which will continue feeding results of hash back into sha256 5 million times.

```js
const sha256 = require('sha256');
const fs = require('fs');
const secret = "Secret";
const max = 5e6; // shorthand for 5 million

let output = secret;
let hash = secret;
let i = 0;
while(i++ < max){
   hash = sha256(hash);
   output += `\n${hash}`;
}

console.log('done', hash);

// save results
const fileName = "path/to/file/output.csv"; // overwrite for desired name
fs.writeFile(fileName, output, err => console.log(err));
```

I suspect that this will be **very** slow if you want to track the results of each hash and then write that into a file. You should first try to run this block for smaller values of `max` and go from there. Once you feel confident in this, remove the steps that build the output string and print results.

Comment: This checks all of the boxes I need for the function. I know it won't be fast but I'm expecting it to take some time. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: this will not be fast, and is only a *very* naive approach**

Using a `pipe` function from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/pipe-and-compose-in-javascript-5b04004ac937/ we can define `f(g(x))` as `pipe(f,g)(x)`.

So we can then use `Array(5,000,000).fill(f)` to give us 5 million references to a function `f`.

Then we can pass that to the argument for `pipe`, and that will return to us a function which will run the function `f` 5 million times passing the return from one to the input of the next.

```js
const pipe = (fns) => (x) => fns.reduce((v, f) => f(v), x);
const addOne = (x) => x+1;

const arrayOfFuncs = Array(5_000_000).fill(addOne);

const addOneChungus = pipe(arrayOfFuncs);

console.log(
  addOneChungus(0)
);
```

Comment: This is what my girlfriend said would be the math equivalent of what I was doing but it works really well inside of the jsfiddle environment.

Comment: I'm glad a mathematician agrees with me. Today is a good day